# Problems with jQuery function in my ASP.NET MVC4 project

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have ASP.NET MVC4 project. I create modal popup window and I'm using jQuery library to make the window draggable.

Here is the code:

```
@{
    //Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />  
<title>Index</title>

</head>
<body>
<div>
</div>
<style>
      
     #shadow
      {
          position: fixed;
           height: 100%;
          width: 100%;
          background-color: #fffddd;
          opacity: 0.4;
          z-index: 9000;
     }
    
    #popUpWin
    {
        border: 3px solid gray;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: white;
        top: 5%;
        left: 30%;
        border-radius: 10px;
        z-index: 9005;
    }
    
    .upperLine
    {
        cursor: move;
        width: 95%;
        height: 20px;
        border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    }
    
    .title
    {
        width: 90%;
        height: 20px;
        font-size: 20;
        font-weight: 900;
        color: gray;
        background-color: white;
    }
    
    #img_close
    {
        top: 2px;
        width: 3%;
        height: 15px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 96%;
        cursor: pointer;
        z-index: 100;
    }
    
    #title_left
    {
        padding: 4px 10px 3px 9px;
        float: left;
        font-size: 10pt;
    }
    
    #content
    {
        background-color: #C0C0C0;
        padding: 4px 10px 3px 9px;
    }
    
    #lowerLine
    {
        width: 100%;
        height: 30px;
        font-size: 14;
        background-color: white;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 3%;
    }
    
    #btnOk
    {
        position: absolute;
        padding: 4px 10px 3px 9px;
        right: 2%;
        background-color: #C0C0C0;
    }
    
    #tempLine
    {
        cursor: move;
        width: 100%;
        height: 30px;
        font-size: 14;
        background-color: green;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 3%;
    }
</style>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        popup('<div><h3>Some Content</h3></div>', 'Choose Your Contacts:', 450, 500)
    });

    function popup(content, title, height, width) {
        var html = '<div id = "popUpWin" style = "width:' + width + 'px; height:' + height + 'px;">';
        html += '<div class="upperLine">';
        html += '<img id = "img_close" src = "fileclose.png" onclick="ClosePopUpWin()" >';
        html += '</div>';
        html += '<div class="title">';
        html += '<span id ="title_left">' + title + '</span>';
        html += '</div>';
        html += '<div id = "content">' + content + '</div>';

        html += '<div id = "lowerLine">';
        html += '<button id = "btnOk" onclick="setContacts()" >OK</button>';
        html += '</div>';
        html += '</div>';

        $('<div></div>').prependTo('body').attr('id', 'shadow');
        $('body').append(html);
        $('#popUpWin').draggable({
            handle: ".upperLine"
        });
    }

    //close popup
    function ClosePopUpWin() {
        $('#popUpWin').fadeOut('fast');
        $('#shadow').remove();
        $('#popUpWin').remove();
    }

    function setContacts() {
        alert("contacts selected");

    }
</script>
```

The problem is that I get this error:

> TypeError: $(...).draggable is not a function

I think that the problame is because the library declared up the page not loaded (by the way the same code works perfect in ASP.NET project(not MVC)).

Here is the screenshot of my Solution Explorer:

[image]

What might be the problem, and why do I get the error above?

Comment: Double check  whether the corresponding js files loaded (check console for 404 errors if any) also if you are using mvc and if there is any Layout page for this view include you JS file in Layout

Comment: The Layout  page set to null

Comment: the js files are in which folder ? Can you tell the hierarchy i suspect it is the issue

Comment: They are in project level

Comment: Okay and are there any console errors saying file not found for js files. i guess your path may not be appropriate  usually the Script  files will be in Scripts folder until and unless you have plced them else where <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Comment: I added a screenshot.You can see where I placed the jquery files.

Comment: This error I get in console window :
TypeError: $(...).draggable is not a function 
$('#popUpWin').draggable({

Comment: @Michael you said layout is set to null. But it is commented

Comment: Yes, but is it not the same?

Comment: No Setting it to null is different from commenting. By just commenting  it you may have a chance of loading Layout page which is set in ViewStart page and there by having a chance of loading incompatible js file

Comment: @Vivekh,thanks for help I uncomment the layout = null and everything works perfect!!!

Comment: You can try dragging and dropping jquery & jqueryui libraries from the solution explorer panel to the cshtml and check paths from there.

Answer (score 0):

Here are few cases that may cause this problem ..

- Your jquery files is not be loaded (404 error).
- You  have added custom jquery UI file in which draggable feature is not included.
- Your jquery UI file version  is incompatible with core jquery file.

Comment: and why not use .. @Url.Content("~/<your path to jquery file>") if this is path related problem

Answer (score 0):

IIS will not allow GET for static file in root path `"~/jquery-ui.min.js"` by default

just move your *.js file to `"~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"`

OR

if you really want to use the root path (not recommend though)

add static file handler into web.config

```
<configuration>
  <!-- ... -->
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <!-- .... -->
      <add name="StaticFile"
           path="*.js" verb="*"
           modules="StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule"
           resourceType="Either"
           requireAccess="Read" />
    </handlers>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".*" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```